# webpack 4 optimization different chunk naming between dev and prod build

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

I'm trying to create a single vendor chunk file by using the optimization in Webpack4. I'm a bit confused thou on how the naming works even after reading the documentation.

```
...
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "RootSite/SiteAssets/js/[Name]_bundle.js",
    libraryTarget: "var",
    library: ["spdict", "[name]"],
},
...
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                name: "vendor",
                chunks: "all"
            }
        }
    }
},
```

When i run `webpack --mode development`, it generates the following files:

- vendor.vendor_bundle.js
- vendor.vendor_bundle.js.map

When I run `webpack --mode production`, it generates the following:

- 0.vendor_bundle.js
- 0.vendor_bundle.js.map

---

Why is there a difference in the naming between the two modes?

Also, why is it *vendor.vendor_bundle.js* instead of just *vendor_bundle.js*?

Comment: the second one, you meant production?

Comment: also, fix here: `filename: "RootSite/SiteAssets/js/[name]_bundle.js"`, does the result still the same?

Comment: @Matheus Silva, yes sorry, that had to be production.

Comment: Also, fixing the filename from [Name] to [name] solved the issue, feel free to add it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Name]`is not a webpack recognizable pattern, this would result in unexpected behaviors. Try:

```
...
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: "RootSite/SiteAssets/js/[name]_bundle.js",
    libraryTarget: "var",
    library: ["spdict", "[name]"],
},
```